# Big error when trying to set up Github pages

Tags: javascript, github, npm, create-react-app

Trying to set up project on github pages, but during following steps from
[here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)
at step 2 I getting this error from images
Any idea?
I working on Win7
with NPM 5.6.0
Node 8.11.3

[image]

Comment: Don't include screen shots of text. Instead, just copy and paste the text directly into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates you need to elevate your shell's permission.

Use your environment's equivalent of `sudo`/"Run as Administrator" to grant the proper access to perform the functions required to install.

Comment: Thanks,  I had also corrupted node_modules file

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to *run as administrator*, like so: `sudo npm install --save gh-pages`.

Or if you'd running on Windows could be:

1. *right-click* on CLI icon
2. *open as administrator*
3. Perform your command (now you're administrator)

Comment: Thanks,  I had also corrupted node_modules file